# how to get not matching value by comparing array of objects and arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have array of object and array, get the not matching array in javascript

for given array object `arrobj` and array `arr`

if `clientid` of arrobj has value in arr,

return not matching values on array from `arr`

I tried

```
const result = arrobj.find(mem => arr.includes(mem.clientId))
```

```
var arrobj =  [
  {
    "caseTaskId": 207,
    "clientId": 7831
  },
  {
    "caseTaskId": 207,
    "clientId": 7833
  },
  {
    "caseTaskId": 207,
    "clientId": 7834
  }
]

var arr = [7834,7832]

Expected Output

[7832]
```

Answer (score 2):

**`SOLUTION 1`**

You can make use of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here as:

`set` will contain all `arrobj`'s `clientId`. So all you have to do is to loop over `arr` and then `filter` out the `not present` id.

```js
var arrobj = [
    {
        caseTaskId: 207,
        clientId: 7831,
    },
    {
        caseTaskId: 207,
        clientId: 7833,
    },
    {
        caseTaskId: 207,
        clientId: 7834,
    },
];

var arr = [7834, 7832];
const set = new Set(arrobj.map((o) => o.clientId));
const result = arr.filter((no) => !set.has(no));
console.log(result);
```

---

**`SOLUTION 2`**

You can also use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) here as:

```js
var arrobj = [
    {
        caseTaskId: 207,
        clientId: 7831,
    },
    {
        caseTaskId: 207,
        clientId: 7833,
    },
    {
        caseTaskId: 207,
        clientId: 7834,
    },
];

var arr = [7834, 7832];
const result = arr.filter((no) => !arrobj.find((o) => o.clientId === no));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `for` loops and `Array.splice()`

```js
// Data
const arrobj =  [
  {
    "caseTaskId": 207,
    "clientId": 7831
  },
  {
    "caseTaskId": 207,
    "clientId": 7833
  },
  {
    "caseTaskId": 207,
    "clientId": 7834
  }
];

const arr = [7834,7832];

// Loop in loop
for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) for(el of arrobj) if(arr[i] == el.clientId) arr.splice(i, 1);

// Test
console.log(arr);
```